# Web Api returning 500 internal server error

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am beating my head against the keyboard trying to figure out why this is happening. I am testing from Swagger (running the application locally) and getting a 500 back. No other details. I am not able to debug the issue because I am not able to hit any breakpoints in my code. Can anyone see from the code below where my error is?

**Error:**

```
Response body
Download
{
  "StatusCode": 500,
  "Message": "Internal Server Error."
}
Response headers
 cache-control: no-cache 
 content-type: application/json 
 date: Wed, 12 Feb 2020 14:49:28 GMT 
 expires: -1 
 pragma: no-cache 
 server: Kestrel 
 status: 500
```

**Code:**

```
[Route("api/v1/BusinessProcesses")]
        [ApiController]

        public class ProcessAssessmentController : EntityController<ProcessAssessment> {

            [AllowAnonymous]
            [HttpGet("{businessProcessId}/DocumentsDetails", Name = "GetDocumentDetailsSummary")]
            [ProducesResponseType(typeof(DocumentSummaryViewModel), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
            [Produces("application/json")]
            [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
            [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
            [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
            [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity)]
            [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetProcessDocumentDetails(string businessProcessId)
                {
                    <some details>.....

                    return Ok(documentSummary);
                }
        }
```

Comment: Read [ask]. Debug your code. Provide a [mre]. You removed the relevant code.

Comment: I posted the error and gave a more detailed explanation in my description of the issue. Sorry about that.

Comment: No, a "500 Internal Server Error" is just a blanket statement for "something went wrong". Debug your code, enable error reporting, add logging. We can't say anything, other than "the problem most likely is somewhere in `<some details>`".

Comment: Close but the issue could not be debugged since my code within the method was not being executed. That is how I knew it was something external to the method invocation.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I did not have my controller registered in the Startup.cs file. I logged it to AppInsights and saw there was an issue resolving a dependency on a service in my constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue tonight, debugging a Web API that is doing user authentication. I am testing my API on localhost, which made it easier to catch problems like this (rather than running the API on a remote or cloud server with its own error log). What helped me most was opening up the Windows Event Viewer.  Search in your search box for "Event Viewer" and open the app.  Then click Windows Logs on the left side, and then Application.

You should see a list of errors. Select one with a date/time of when you got the 500 error on your localhost page.  Here's one of the ones mine captured, with a Source of ".NET Runtime":

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

Exception: 
System.NotSupportedException: Store does not implement IUserRoleStore<TUser>.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GetUserRoleStore()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GetRolesAsync(TUser user)
   at Crums.API.Controllers.CrumUsersController.Authenticate(LoginRequest loginDetail) in [...]
```

That should help debug a HTTP 500 error.